# Flutter: Using AbsorbPointer and change the look of the Widgets

Tags: flutter

How i can change the appearance of several Widgets inside a AbsorbPointer? I know using AbsorbPointer that it paints is children as usual. But is it possible that depending on some condition the widgets would get the appearance like they would be disable.
Thanks in advance for some help.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isDisabled = false;
  bool isSwitched = false;
  double _value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Switch(
              value: isDisabled,
              onChanged: (check) {
                setState(() {
                  isDisabled = check;
                });
              }),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          AbsorbPointer(
            absorbing: !isDisabled,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Switch(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        isSwitched = value;
                      });
                    },
                    value: isSwitched),
                Slider(
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: 100.0,
                  value: _value,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _value = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('BUTTON'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `final absorber = context.findAncestorRenderObjectOfType<RenderAbsorbPointer>(); print(absorber?.absorbing);`

Comment: @pskink thanks for the quick response. I am not understanding how i can use this?!?!

Comment: Use that code in child widget to see if there is a parent `AbsorbPointer` widget

Answer (score 0):

I changed the appearance like this. My approached looks for me, like a lot of code. Is there some better way to make this?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isDisabled = false;
  bool isSwitched = false;
  double _value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Switch(
              value: isDisabled,
              onChanged: (check) {
                setState(() {
                  isDisabled = check;
                });
              }),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          AbsorbPointer(
            absorbing: !isDisabled,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Switch(
                  value: isSwitched,
                  activeColor: isDisabled
                      ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 187, 106)
                      : Colors.grey.shade600,
                  activeTrackColor: isDisabled
                      ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 243, 193)
                      : Colors.grey.shade400,
                  inactiveThumbColor: isDisabled
                      ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 18, 18)
                      : Colors.grey.shade600,
                  inactiveTrackColor: isDisabled
                      ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 250, 142, 142)
                      : Colors.grey.shade400,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isSwitched = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Slider(
                  activeColor: isDisabled
                      ? const Color(0xFFEF6C00)
                      : Colors.grey.shade600,
                  inactiveColor: isDisabled
                      ? const Color(0xFFEF6C00)
                      : Colors.grey.shade600,
                  thumbColor: isDisabled
                      ? const Color(0xFFEF6C00)
                      : Colors.grey.shade600,
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: 100.0,
                  value: _value,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _value = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: isDisabled
                        ? MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)
                        : MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            Colors.grey.shade600,
                          ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('BUTTON'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```